# When paused on a statement within the browser's dev tools, how to terminate execution immediately after that statement?

Tags: javascript, debugging, browser, google-chrome-devtools

Let's say I have this function:

```
function test () {

    // statements 1

    statement_X;

    // statements 2

}
```

I'm stepping trough the statements with the browser's dev tools. Now, when I'm paused at "statement_X", I would like to terminate the function execution (I don't want the "statements 2" part of the function to be executed), as if the "statement_X" is immediately followed by a `return;` statement.

I know that Chrome has inline script editing, so I could manually add the return statement after the paused statement and then hit CTRL+S to re-execute the entire thing, but I need this feature for IE too, so I am hoping for a general solution.

Terminating execution early seems like an easy enough thing to do (for the browser), so I expect such a functionality from the dev tools.

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to stop the execution of this specific function or the debuging?

Comment: @rcdmk "Or the debugging"? What do you mean? Or the debugger? No, the debugger should be unaffected by this. (I would like to stop the execution of the function.)

Comment: Than, I think you have no luck with this, like Manishearth pointed out.

Comment: Tried in FireBug and think it's not possible in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested this successfully in IE 9, so I'm posting it here as an answer: while pausing at `statement_X` in the script debugger, hit F10 so `statement_X` is still executed, then right click on the last line of the enclosing function (the line with the right curly bracket `}` that terminates the function body), and select "Set next statement" from the drop down menu. This will skip execution until the end of the function as if there were a void return statement just after `statement_X`.

[image]

If there are any other statements on the last line of a function as shown in the code below, be careful to right click just on the curly bracket for this technique to work.

```
function test () { alert("statement 1");
    alert("statement 2"); } function test2 () { alert("statement 3"); }
```

This may be sometimes necessary in the case of inline functions, or in minified scripts not intended for debugging.

Comment: Set next statement? Cool `:)` What do you mean by that last paragraph?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Whoops! That was really quick and dirty. Just added some more explanation, should be clear now.

Comment: @ft I tried your code and I had to place the caret *before* the curly brace. Clicking *after* the brace resulted in an error popup saying "Unable to set the next statement to this location". This makes sense because the area after the curly brace is not part of the current function execution, but instead part of the outer scope which is not being executed. So, as long as you click the space before the curly brace, you should be fine.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Ok, I see. Feel free to edit the answer if you want. Thanks for accepting.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can't do this.

The debuggers (Chrome's debugger at any rate) are themselves javascript-based.

These guys use `eval()`(eventually) to run the injected Code. Trawling through Chrome inspector, it seems that the debugger code eventually calls this when you try to evaluate something (I think):

```
function (evalFunction, object, expression, isEvalOnCallFrame, injectCommandLineAPI)
{
    // Only install command line api object for the time of evaluation.
    // Surround the expression in with statements to inject our command line API so that
    // the window object properties still take more precedent than our API functions.

    try {
        if (injectCommandLineAPI && inspectedWindow.console) {
            inspectedWindow.console._commandLineAPI = new CommandLineAPI(this._commandLineAPIImpl, isEvalOnCallFrame ? object : null);
            expression = "with ((window && window.console && window.console._commandLineAPI) || {}) {\n" + expression + "\n}";
        }
        return evalFunction.call(object, expression);
    } finally {
        if (injectCommandLineAPI && inspectedWindow.console)
            delete inspectedWindow.console._commandLineAPI;
    }
}
```

`evalFunction` is just an alias for `eval()`.

The issue is, we cannot use return statements in eval, even in hard code. It will always give you `SyntaxError: Illegal return statement`.

So no, no voodoo return statement.

Comment: Well, first of all, it is possible (in Chrome) to inject a return statement right after the paused statement, and then re-run the code (by pressing CTRL+S). I mentioned this in my question, and this is kind-of what I'm looking for. (Ideally, I would like to have a convenient "Terminate" button in the debugger, so that I don't have to manually insert return statements and do CTRL+S all the time.) The problem is that I want this functionality in IE which does not have hot swap (inline code editing)...

Comment: @Šime looks like that is via a native function. Since Chrome's debugger is HTML, I can write a userscript for Chrome that adds a button. Not sure though. And it's not there in IE.