# Does the "Set next statement" feature exist in Chrome's Dev Tools or in Firebug?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

IE's development tools, more specifically its JavaScript debugger, offer a "Set next statement" command, which enables you to specify which statement should be executed next. That way, you can effectively skip certain parts of functions or even (again, effectively) return from a function early.

So, for this function...

```
function test () {
    alert(1);
    alert(2);
    alert(3);
}
```

If we set a break-point on the first alert, and then invoke the function, we can execute the first alert (F10), and then right-click on the third alert and choose "Set next statement". Now, if we press F10, the third alert will be executed, so, effectively, the second alert was skipped.

(Test in IE [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZgS2E/show/):  --- open IE's tools with F12, switch to "Script" tab, set breakpoint, press "Start debugging" button, refresh page if necessary)

I like this "set next statement" feature. However, I did not notice it in Chrome's dev tools or in Firebug. Does this feature exist in those debuggers?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that IE had "Set next statement" I didn't know that so I switched from Chrome to IE for one debugging task

Answer (score 39, accepted):

While Chrome DevTools doesn't have "Set Next Statement", you can more explicitly define next statement by just editing the JavaScript while it's paused at the breakpoint.

I've made a short [screencast](http://youtu.be/ItMcQyXrWF8) for you to show Chrome DevTools Live Edit + Breakpoint Debugging.

In essence: while at a breakpoint, live edit your script by clicking into the Scripts panel and making changes. Hit <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> to save. Then walk through that code with its new changes. Far more powerful than just bypassing code, you could be adding new functionality as well.

Comment: Thanks for the screencast :) Yea, I know about Chrome's inline code editing (I watched the talk you did last year where you introduced it). This is a killer feature which can be used for all kinds of things - for instance, exiting a function early as I mentioned in [my other question here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10229996/). However, I would like to see "set next statement" in Chrome eventually. (Ctrl+S will re-run the function, and I may find myself in the middle of a function where I *don't* want to re-run the entire function again, but still want to skip one or more statements.)

Comment: It's true, you'll have to re-evaluate that function back to the call point. I'm trying to think of cases where I'd want GOTO (essentially) in my debugging, but can't think of my usecases; what is your scenario?

Comment: I use GOTO ("set next statement") in IE in order to skip all subsequent statements of a function - this enables me to exit a function at any given statement. I need this because IE freezes the page while the debugger is running, so I have no visual info about what my statements are doing, and the only way to see how the page looked like at a given statement is to do a GOTO to the end of the function. I didn't yet need GOTO in Chrome though...

Comment: Paul, have there been any thoughts on adding this glaring omission from an otherwise very nice debugger? The primary uses are to rerun a code block with different data and to step into a block that didn't work as expected. Changing code is done _after_ debugging. It can take minutes of work to get to a breakpoint, and having to repeat the steps to get back to that breakpoint wastes a ton of time. The Microsoft debuggers have had this feature since QuickBasic. 'Set Next Statement' has even been drag-drop enabled since at least VB5 (17 years ago) in the Visual Studio debugger family.

Comment: @PaulIrish is it still the best solution today ? I see many usecases: when you want to skip some lines of code, when you want to re-run the *n* last lines, when you want to fall into an *else* statement where the code should have gone into the *if* one, when you've changed an object's property on the fly and want to re-run the last line with the new value, & so on... Code editing is pretty cool but looks like overkill for this "GOTO" feature imho, and not as fast as drag-n-droping the "next instruction cursor" to its new location. Also, this would complement "Restart frame" awesome feature :)

Comment: @PaulIrish One major use case is when you run a line of code and need to examine it again without re-running the entire execution. I use this functionality all the time in Visual Studio to help pinpoint where the bug is occurring.

Comment: Yeah. I agree that this should exist. If we set multiple ```debugger``` statements in our script it would be helpful to be able to pause on each as the parser passes each subsequent one. As it exists now, it will only pause on the first ```debugger``` statement and if I resume the execution it will skip all subsequent debuggers.

Comment: @PaulIrish, as you point in your answer, editing source code is the only way to make Chrome restart the execution at the beginning of the method which is being debugged, but this workaround doesn't work with Angular and typescript. Is there a future plan to add this functionality to Chrome?, I'm pretty sure it would be very appreciated by most of the people that face daily (and nightly) debugging. Also, is there any feature request for this? Thanks in advance