# Does Chrome debugger have an equavalent of "Set Next Statement" in IE

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome

Does Chrome JS debugger have the equivalent of "Set Next Statement" in IE?
Sometimes it is very handy.

Also, is there a way to delete all expressions from the "Watch Expressions" window ?

Comment: With [remote debugging](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging) enabled, [setScriptSource](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/protocol/1.0/debugger#command-setScriptSource) or [evaluateOnCallFrame](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/protocol/1.0/debugger#command-evaluateOnCallFrame) may be able to emulate "Set Next Statement". There's no mouse or keyboard shortcut to clear the watchlist.

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10318197/does-the-set-next-statement-feature-exist-in-chromes-dev-tools-or-in-firebug